# C# set properties by name in string of Field list

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I get all instance of object with this code:

```
 Type type = this.GetType();
 FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                     BindingFlags.Instance);
```

but i can't change property such as `Enabled` for buttons 
because `SetValue` get target of instance Class and i dont have this. i have just name and type of class.
now how to  change property(Enabled) of objects that exist in fields.

Comment: Your instance is `this`. You are getting your Type from an instance of the class.

Comment: There is no meaning to changing the `Enabled` property of something that doesn't exist.    Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do and why?

Comment: To reiterate @PaulSasik If the type you're looking at is the type of the `this` instance, your instance would be `this`

Answer (score 1):

try modifying your reflection code slightly.  For one thing, you have to reference both the object, and the `property` that you specifically want.  Remember, `Property` is not the same as `Field`.

```
MyObject.GetType().GetProperty("Enabled").SetValue(MyObject, bEnabled, null);
```

you use the type of whatever `MyObject` is, be that a button or a form or whatever...then you reference the property by name `Enabled`, then you set it back against `MyObject`.

if you want to fetch the properties before hand you can store the instances in a variable, but again remember that properties aren't fields.

```
PropertyInfo[] piSet = MyObject.GetType().GetProperties();
```

you can use `this` to get the property set, but its not recommended if `this` is not of the same `Type` as the control you are trying to enable/disable.

**Added Edit**

After re-reading the question I got this out of it: What you seem to want is multi-layer reflection and generics.  The control you are looking for is a Field attached to "this".  What you can do is something along these lines.

```
Type theType = this.GetType();
FieldInfo[] fi = theType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach ( FieldInfo f in fi)
{
    //Do your own object identity check
    //if (f is what im looking for)
    {
        Control c = f.GetValue(this) as Control;
        c.Enabled = bEnabled;
    }
    //Note: both sets of code do the same thing
    //OR you could use pure reflection
    {
        f.GetValue(this).GetType().GetProperty("Enabled").SetValue(f.GetValue(this), bEnabled, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are actually using the fields of the object. If you truly want writable properties, then you want something like this:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(Public | SetProperty | Instance);
```

Once you have that, your enabled property might be set thus:

```
myenabledPropertyInfo.SetValue(targetObject, value, null);
```

where targetobject is the object whose Enabled property we are interested in, and value is the value we wish to assign (in this case, presumably a boolean...)

Hope that helps...